# class A cannot be cast to class A

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a REST API in Java SpringBoot using Hibernate JPA and SQL Server as database.

My app throws the following Exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.estrelladekleene.safetycar.dto.DriverDTO cannot be cast to class com.estrelladekleene.safetycar.dto.DriverDTO (com.estrelladekleene.safetycar.dto.DriverDTO is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; com.estrelladekleene.safetycar.dto.DriverDTO is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @47e566be)

The problem appears in the following lines of code

```
public DriverDTO getDriverByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    DriverDTO driverDTO= entityManager.createQuery("SELECT d FROM DriverDTO d WHERE d.phoneNumber="+phoneNumber,DriverDTO.class).getSingleResult();
    return driverDTO;
}
```

This is my DriverDTO class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Driver")

public class DriverDTO {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "phoneNumber")
private String phoneNumber;

@Column(name = "fullName")
private String fullName;

@Column(name = "mail")
private String mail;

@Column(name = "batteryPercentage")
private Integer batteryPercentage;

@Column(name = "firebaseId")
private String firebaseId;

public DriverDTO() {
}

public DriverDTO(Long id, String phoneNumber, String fullName, String mail, Integer batteryPercentage, String firebaseId) {
    this.id = id;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.mail = mail;
    this.batteryPercentage = batteryPercentage;
    this.firebaseId = firebaseId;
}
```

This is my database Table and as you can see the Columns matches DriverDTO class:
[image]

When I do the following I have no problem at all:

```
public List<DriverDTO> getAllDrivers() {
    List<DriverDTO> driverDTOS = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT d FROM DriverDTO d", DriverDTO.class).getResultList();
    return driverDTOS;
}
```

I can't seem to do a simple where query. I also tried querying this way: entityManager.find(DriverDTO.class,1); and it doesn't work either. In my database does exist id=1 row.

[image]

Comment: Different class loaders?

Comment: As per the [*How to ask* guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: This is ALWAYS caused by the same class being loaded via two different classloaders.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen where do I check that?

Comment: @JimGarrison I don't understand much about classloaders but I've done the same thing as this code before in other projects and I've never had a problem and it's worked perfectly. It is the first time that it happens to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after a lot of research I found that this problem is related to spring dev tools package. My solution was removing the package from my pom.xml that in my case wasn't required.